# Why is MongoDB tailable cursor logged as slow?

Tags: mongodb

I'm using a tailable cursor to read through a trace collection ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor ). This seems to work fine, but I'm getting the following slow queries logged:

```
Tue Jan 15 17:54:37 [conn28] getmore trace.traces query: { time: { $gte: new Date(1358254406370) } } cursorid:7095190436798608732 reslen:20 2268ms
Tue Jan 15 17:54:38 [conn28] getmore trace.traces query: { time: { $gte: new Date(1358254406370) } } cursorid:7095190436798608732 nreturned:1 reslen:513 315ms
Tue Jan 15 17:54:39 [conn28] getmore trace.traces query: { time: { $gte: new Date(1358254406370) } } cursorid:7095190436798608732 nreturned:2 reslen:1800 962ms
Tue Jan 15 17:54:41 [conn28] getmore trace.traces query: { time: { $gte: new Date(1358254406370) } } cursorid:7095190436798608732 reslen:20 2268ms
Tue Jan 15 17:54:43 [conn28] getmore trace.traces query: { time: { $gte: new Date(1358254406370) } } cursorid:7095190436798608732 reslen:20 2283ms
```

The line keeps being logged every few seconds, even when not writing to the collection at all.

I'm using Mongo 2.0.8 (and the Java Driver 2.10.1). I've also tried it on Mongo 2.2.2, but here it is not logged (even with --profile 2), however, I still see it in the system.profile collection.

Does anyone know why this query is (reported as) slow?

Here is the profile info:

```
> db.system.profile.find().limit(1).sort( { millis : -1 } ).pretty()
{
    "ts" : ISODate("2013-01-15T17:33:48.354Z"),
    "op" : "getmore",
    "ns" : "trace.traces",
    "query" : {
            "time" : {
                    "$gte" : ISODate("2013-01-15T12:56:57.589Z")
            }
    },
    "cursorid" : NumberLong("8205177764687670896"),
    "ntoreturn" : 0,
    "keyUpdates" : 0,
    "numYield" : 0,
    "lockStats" : {
            "timeLockedMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(30492),
                    "w" : NumberLong(0)
            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(22499),
                    "w" : NumberLong(3)
            }
    },
    "nreturned" : 0,
    "responseLength" : 20,
    "millis" : 2356,
    "client" : "127.0.0.1",
    "user" : ""
}
```

Here are the stats of the collection:

```
> db.traces.stats()
{
    "ns" : "trace.traces",
    "count" : 41897,
    "size" : 51760464,
    "avgObjSize" : 1235.4217247058261,
    "storageSize" : 52432896,
    "numExtents" : 1,
    "nindexes" : 1,
    "lastExtentSize" : 52432896,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "systemFlags" : 1,
    "userFlags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 1422624,
    "indexSizes" : {
            "_id_" : 1422624
    },
    "capped" : true,
    "max" : 2147483647,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your cursor blocks waiting for new documents when there are no available documents. See that slow queries have all `reslen:20`. This looks like a normal behavior to me.

Comment: The thought did occur to me. It is a shame that it keeps cluttering up my log and profile data, though.